# How to filter neighbour rows (first, prev, next, last) from the query result?

Tags: subquery, mysql-5.5

I am working on a quick-links solution for a big set of records. Records are ordered by user (criteria not relevant here) and I have built the list of IDs. Now, I managed to add a position to each ID.

```
SELECT
     cp.id,
     cp.page_name,
     @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS `position`
FROM couch_pages cp
JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
WHERE cp.template_id = '2'
ORDER BY cp.publish_date DESC
```

Table `couch_pages` has `id`, `template_id`, `page_name`, `publish_date` and a lot of other columns. Client can request arbitrary order of IDs. I must follow the lead and recalculate position every time.

What I do not know is whether it is possible to calc not only position for the whole set, but also get a position of an arbitrary ID, for example, `cp.id = '1600'` and receive prev-next-last-first records in a single query.

Result of the query above looks simple -

```
"id"    "page_name" "position"

"1578"   "late-in-the-evening"  "1"
"1600"   "thats-why-god-made-"  "2"
"1599"   "god-bless-the-absen"  "3"
............................
"124601" "loves-me-like-a-ro"   "122703"
```

At the moment, I am sending the whole result to PHP array and able to find a matched record (for example, with id="1600") and its neighbors - previous record (id="1578"), next record, first and last records.

I would like to *not* send the whole subset to the client, because I anticipate the number of records can explode and script would become much slower.

Is it possible to filter required (prev, next, last, first) records for a given ID from the results?

Comment: why don't you use limit and offset and let php send you those values, and to determine if the records are at an end you can add another column with the `count` of all values, then php will know it's at an end if `tb.position=tb.total_rows`

Comment: @darklightcode, if I add to the query `AND cp.id='1600'` my `position` will always be "1". PHP doesn't know the offset for a given id, because it doesn't know its position yet.

Comment: @darklightcode I have fixed the question. Please check if anything else need be done about it..

Answer (score 0):

Using [Cross JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) I created a new column for your records to determine which is the first record and which is the last one. As stated in my first comment, a `count(*)` should suffice because we can check it against the `position` column.

> In MySQL, JOIN, **CROSS JOIN**, and INNER JOIN are syntactic equivalents (they can replace each other). In standard SQL, they are not equivalent. **INNER JOIN is used with an ON clause, CROSS JOIN is used otherwise**.

Try the code below:

```sql
    SELECT
    a.*,
    (
    CASE

            WHEN a.position = 1 
            AND a.position = c.total_records THEN
                3 -- Mark only if you have one record 3 = (1 and 2) at the same time

                WHEN a.position = 1 THEN
                1 -- Mark first record with 1

                WHEN a.position = c.total_records THEN
                2 -- Mark last record with 2
                ELSE 0 
            END 
            ) AS row_status 
        FROM
            ( SELECT count( * ) AS total_records FROM couch_pages ) c
            CROSS JOIN (
            SELECT
                x.id,
                x.page_name,
                x.position 
            FROM
                (
                SELECT
                    t.id,
                    t.page_name,
                    @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position 
                FROM
                    couch_pages t
                    JOIN ( SELECT @rownum := 0 ) r 
                -- ORDER BY
                    -- cast( SUBSTR( t.page_name, 5 ) AS INT ) -- Order by the INT part of your page_name

                ) x 
            ) a 
    LIMIT 4 OFFSET 3;-- This is the line you should adjust using PHP, you can keep the values in POST or GET like FQDN/?page=3&records_per_page=4
```

Comment: Thanks. I will carefully study your query. I am sorry to say, but pageX was unintentional naming which is misleading. No, page_name doesn't store a position in it. Real-life page_name is just an Article's Title. I will edit my question immediately.

Comment: @AntonS. i have also updated my query by adding a comment to "order by" and "cast"

Comment: The normal answer on this case, is just limit your query results, and do the prev/current/next logic in PHP.